# Is it correct to use "run the gamut" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality, phrase-usage, usage, idioms

I searched the samples of using "run the gamut", but I could not find a case in which it is used at the beginning of a sentence. I was wondering whether my sentence is correct?

> Run the gamut from the early nomadic tribes to the skyscraper cities, laws were central pillars in making societies.

Comment: Your sentence would make more sense if it was: "Running the gamut from the early..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that "run the gamut" begins with the word "run". "Run" is a verb and normally requires a subject. While "run the gamut" is a specific idiom, it does not break this rule.

Normally in English the subject comes before the verb. So we would expect to see "[subject] runs the gamut ...", i.e. some subject coming before the word "run". Like, "Posters on ELL run the gamut from Americans to Britons to Indians to people from countries where English is not commonly spoken at all."

That said, English word order is not totally inflexible. You can write sentences that vary it, usually for emphasis or poetic style. For example, "Running the gamut from Americans to Japanese, posters on ELL are a diverse group."

Imperative sentences have an implied subject of "you", and so often begin with a verb. Like, "Run away!" But an imperative sentence using "run the gamut" seems unlikely.

Your example sentence doesn't make much sense to me. Who or what is running the gamut here? It is not the subject of the second clause, "laws". Laws do not run the gamut from nomadic tribes to skyscraper cities. Those aren't kinds of laws. The sentence mentions "societies". Those could be kinds of societies.

I think the writer meant something like, "In societies running the gamut from nomadic tribes to skyscraper cities, laws were central pillars in making them function."

Answer (score 2):

Your example

> Run the gamut from the early nomadic tribes to the skyscraper cities, laws were central pillars in making societies.

contains two sentences separated by a comma, which in this case is a [comma splice](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/the-comma-splice-american?q=The+comma+splice).

Two grammatically correct versions of your sentence, with the idiom at the beginning, are

> Running the gamut from the early nomadic tribes to the skyscraper cities, laws were central pillars in making societies.

In this sentence, *laws* are what run the gamut. This seems to equate *laws* with *early nomadic tribes* and *skyscraper cities*, which does not make sense.

and

> Run the gamut from the early nomadic tribes to the skyscraper cities, and (you (will)) see that laws were central pillars in making societies.

In this sentence, an imperative, the reader (*you*) is running the gamut.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the idiom 'run the gamut', which takes a subject **in most cases**. This is the reason when we search the exact string on COCA, it does not show any result that ***starts*** with this idiom.

[MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/gamut) quotes an example with the idiom's meaning:

> *run the gamut (=include the widest possible range)*: **Prices** in the restaurants **run the gamut** from cheap to very expensive.

Examples from the [FreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+the+gamut) have *something* in front of 'run the gamut'.

**However,** I see no problem in using the idiom to begin the sentence. It is a style of writing. The nouns and pronouns can be placed *later* when we use such idioms. I found an example on [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/from-pillar-to-post)

> After being bandied **from pillar to post** for about twenty minutes, **she** finally got connected to a Voice.

---

However, I see no requirement of using the idiom in the given sentence. Also, the sentence looks strange. What is the source of the sentence? (Is it *where* or *were*?)

Comment: -1 because, among other things, it is extremely difficult to extract from this post an answer to the simple question: is the OP's sentence correct or not? In addition, the example of a second idiom seems only to further befuddle the issue.

Comment: In fact (or, in effect), this post seems to say the sample question of the OP is correct as written, which is not at all the case.

Comment: @pazzo I addressed the 'title' -to begin a sentence with that idiom. Every line of this answer addresses that in fact! Not sure what you read out of the context here! :) But I appreciate coming up with a comment, stating that you downvoted and with a reason,l which is quite rare here these days.

Comment: All right, and I understand that sometimes the question in *the question title* does not really reflect (= is not the same as) the question asked in the *body of the question*. Sometimes it seems one can answer one or the other. I have done this in the past. I dunno, best policy might be to answer the question in the body.